# Updating documents with SOLR

Tags: solr

I have a community website with 20.000 members using everyday a search form to find other members. The results are sorted by the last connected members. I'd like to use Solr for my search (right now it's mysql) but I'd like to know first if it's good practice to update the document of every member who would login in order to change their login date and time ? There will be around 20.000 update of documents a day, I don't really know if it's too much updating and could alter performances ? Tank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20k updates/day is not unreasonable at all for Solr.

OTOH, for very frequently updating fields (imagine one user could log in multiple times a day so you might want to update it all those times), you can use [External Fields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes) to keep that field stored outside the index (in a text file) and still use it for sorting in solr.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, that's really interesting and might be really useful ! So If I understand, after storing this field in an external .txt file, I just build my solr query using this field like it's actually in the index even if it isn't ?

Comment: check the wiki and doc, but yes

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Solr does not be used for **this purpose**, using your database is still better.

However, if you want to use Solr, you will deal with it in a way like the database. i.e every `user` document should has a unique field, `id` for example. When the user make log in, you may use an update query for that user's document `last_login_date` field by its `id`. You could able to know more about *Partial Update* from [**this link**](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/).

Comment: Thank you, partial update was what I had in mind, so even if there is more than 20.000 partial documents updated every day, solr can take it without any performance problem ?

Comment: I have a Solr collation that add more than 4000 new documents every day with total indexed documents till now more than 2 million document. It should works fine. However, you may have to increase the memory settings of Tomcat. -If you use Tomcat as a server of course-